# Where is tensor_forest in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a random forest using `tensorflow 2.0`. I have looked at a number of examples (https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/random_forest.py), but these are not compatible with `tensorflow 2.0`. I am trying to figure out if `tensor_forests` are supported in 2.0 and where I can find them.

I know that the contrib module is unsupported and the modules are supposed to have moved to either the core or addons. However, I can't find any mentions of where it has moved to. I have run the background script and it does not solve the problem. I have also tried just removing the contrib symbols as suggested on the migration guide to no success.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testFileUpgraded.py", line 12, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensor_forest.python import tensor_forest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180626-tensor-forest.md

Comment: Thanks @WilliamD.Irons. It seems like it is not implemented yet, but there is a RFC proposal to move it into the canned estimators. The review will remain open until july 16th if anybody has any comments: https://github.com/tensorflow/community/pull/3

Comment: More than a year later, does anyone know if tensor_forest has shown up again somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

**tensorflow.contrib** module has been dropped as of tensor_flow v2.0.0 see [issue #93](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/issues/93)

Unfortunately it looks as though there is still work to be done in migrating some of the modules under contrib into other modules. **tensor_forest** module will be moved to **core**, but this has not been done yet

[image]

**Full details [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md)**